# Only playing Spritely animation on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-sprites

I am currently creating an animation in jQuery using Spritely.

How would i go about playing the animation once on mouse over and then stopping the animation on mouse out...

Any Help would be great thanks, Here is the current code:

```
(function($) {
            $('#booth').bind("mouseenter", function() {
                $('#phone').sprite({fps: 24, no_of_frames: 36})
                $(this).unbind();
            });

            $('#booth').bind("mouseout", function() {
                $(this).stop();
                $(this).unbind();
            });
        })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Are you still looking for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Spritely documentation, it looks like `.spStop()` is the method you want:

```
        $('#booth').bind("mouseout", function() {
            $(this).spStop();
            $(this).unbind();
        });
```

Comment: hey thanks for the quick response... but no didnt seem to work.. i am still looking around..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `.destroy()`

Making your code:

```
$('#booth').bind("mouseout", function() {
     $(this).destroy();
      $(this).unbind();
});`
```

I have been using it, and the destroy method stops the animation.